# remapping with robot_state_publisher

Tags: ros, remapping, robot-state-publisher, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the arm_navigation stack and can't seem to remap a published sensor_msgs/JointState topic through the robot_state_publisher generic launch file. The remapping and tf file is:

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" name="rob_st_pub" >
      <remap from="joint_states_tf" to="joint_states" />
    </node>
</launch>
```

The topic is published correctly (verified with rostopic echo) under "/joint_states_tf" through this node

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sensor_msgs/JointState.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    ros::init(argc,argv,"state_publisher");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::JointState>("joint_states_tf",1000);
    ros::Rate lr(10);

    sensor_msgs::JointState msg;
    msg.name.push_back("tip_joint");
    msg.name.push_back("wrist_roll_joint");
    msg.name.push_back("wrist_flex_joint");
    msg.name.push_back("wrist_roll_joint");
    msg.name.push_back("elbow_flex_joint");
    msg.name.push_back("shoulder_lift_joint");
    msg.name.push_back("shoulder_roll_joint");
    msg.name.push_back("base_joint");
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        msg.position.push_back(0.0);
        msg.velocity.push_back(0.0);
        msg.effort.push_back(0.0);
    }

    while(ros::ok()){
        msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
        pub.publish(msg);
        ros::spinOnce();
    }
}
```

yet the output when using

```
rostopic echo /joint_states
```

is null and but the /tf topic is published correctly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35314/remapping-with-robot_state_publisher/) by [ocli](https://answers.ros.org/users/2452/ocli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 215 on 2012-05-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have it flipped. The remap says from what topic that is named in the binary to what topic in the ROS world it should be remapped.

If you either apply that remapping to you program launch or flip the remap parameters for the state publisher, it should work.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ocli](https://answers.ros.org/users/2452/ocli/) on 2012-05-31**:
I wanted to remap from /joint_states_tf to /joint_states, not vice versa.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-05-31**:
I think your understanding of remapping from/to is wrong. As you have set it up, you need to either remap the other way around or remap the other program. As you do it, it can't work.

**Comment by [ocli](https://answers.ros.org/users/2452/ocli/) on 2012-05-31**:
I think that's very likely. I just switched them around and slowed the loop rate and it works, what is the purpose of robot state planner tutorial launch file where it remaps the non-existent publication from the /environment server then?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-05-31**:
Are you referring to the example launch file in 2.2? That maps FROM joint_states, which is a topic of robot_state_publisher and thus correct.

**Comment by [ocli](https://answers.ros.org/users/2452/ocli/) on 2012-05-31**:
Yes. Ah ok I got confused when looking at the rxgraph. Thankyou